# Большое количество вложенных ifов требуют укорачивания

Tags: c#, оптимизация

Имеется кусок кода:

```
if (Score[0] == 0)
            {
                Score[0] = c9;
                if (Score[1] == 0)
                {
                    Score[1] = c9;
                    if (Score[2] == 0)
                    {
                        Score[2] = c9;
                        if (Score[3] == 0)
                        {
                            Score[3] = c9;
                            if (Score[4] == 0)
                            {
                                Score[4] = c9;
                                if (Score[5] != 0) Score[5] -= 1;
                            }
                            else Score[4] -= 1;
                        }
                        else Score[3] -= 1;
                    }
                    else Score[2] -= 1;
                }
                else Score[1] -= 1;
            }
            else Score[0] -= 1;
```

Можно ли его укоротить? Мне ничего в голову не пришло.

*с9 - константа*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логика для `Score[5]` немного портит дело, но вот:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (Score[i] == 0) {
    Score[i] = c9;
  } else {
    Score[i] -= 1;
    break;
  }
}
if (i == 5 && Score[5] != 0)
  Score[5] -= 1;
```